# install4j hide installation components based on the media type

Tags: install4j

I want to hide installation components based on the media type. I could not find any API to hide installation types programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in the media file wizard by excluding installation components on the Customize project->Exclude components step.